# Value Of Control Assigned With Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Why when I assign new value of HiddenField control with javascript, the value of HiddenField control in this case remains the same state (5) when I call it with "<%= this.HiddenField.Value %>" ? But when I call it with "console.log(document.getElementById('<%= this.HiddenField.ClientID %>').value);" this return the chagned state in this case "active", why? How I can get the changed value in code behind (I want "<%= this.HiddenField.Value %>" to return "active"(the changed value)) ?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        document.getElementById('<%= this.HiddenField.ClientID %>').value = "active";
        console.log(document.getElementById('<%= this.HiddenField.ClientID %>').value); // this return te changed value "active"
        console.log('<%= this.HiddenField.Value %>') //this again is 5 not "active"
    });
</script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" runat="server" Value="5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

asp.net is a serverside language.
When you use "<%=", it will do the same as a response.write to your html document.
You're changing the value at runtime through jQuery in the client's browser, which obviously occurs after you already write the value to your Log function.

Just look at the generated script, and it should be clear immediately why you get these results.